# Jmeter Debugging- How to Run only 1 simple controller from test plan

Tags: debugging, jmeter, performance-testing

In my test plan ,under a thread group i have 7-8 simple controllers, i am adding or updating new http request within simple controller daily, how can i run only that controller while debugging. after updating i want to run only that particular simple controller and not entire test plan because my test plan has many request i dont want to run all http request while debugging.

Test plan

- thread group
- simple controller 1
- http 1
- http 2
- simple controller 2
  .
  .
  .
- simple controller 7

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to achieve it. one easy solution to that is using Module controller.

For that you need to

1. Right-click on testplan and add a new Thread group
2. Add a module controller
3. Select the target to the simple controller on the other thread group which you wanted to run
4. Now If you run the new thread group - it will execute only the selected simple controller

Something looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. There is possibility to "disable" the "unwanted" test elements from the context menu (right click)

   [image]

   greyed out test elements won't be executed
2. You can use [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to choose which child to run:

   [image]
3. Instead of (or in addition to) Simple Controlles you can use [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference them using [Module Controllers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller):

   [image]